# Understanding source code symlink in a Angular 2 webpack project

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, webpack

I have two Angular2 projects using webpack as module bundler and typescript.

Aiming to share code between, I split some of the source code and created a symlink to this 'external' source code from each of this two projects.

**After doing this the "symlinked code" can not resolve the imports properly**.

below a "hello world" project to shows my concerns.

https://github.com/datracka/angular2-symlink-issue

This project runs straight forward BUT if you remove the given `src` folder and create a symlink to another `src` folder with the same source code BUT located at `/another/path/src` then you get a compiler error:

```
ERROR in .-shared/src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1326:5)
    at ensureTypeScriptInstance (/Users/vicensfayos/Projects/angular2-abc/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:156:103)
    at Object.loader (/Users/vicensfayos/Projects/angular2-abc/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js:403:14)
```

So my question is: what I am missing with symlinks when I "distribute" the source code in another folder out of the project folder itself?

My guess is about configure properly resolving object in webpack https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html to override the node.js loading node_modules algorithm https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders but not luck.

Hopefully somebody can point me in some direction.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

My guess was right. it was about how nodejs resolve the dependencies. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

The symlinked code is trying to find the dependencies moving up all the way failing until it finds `node_module`. But nothing is there. `node_module` is in the parent project.

Therefore the solution is create another symlink from the symlinked code to the `node_modules` folder of the parent project to resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup but decided to add a path to my tsconfig.json in my main app:

```
"paths": {
   "*": ["*", "node_modules/*"]
}
```

All the modules required by the source code in the shared symlinked folders are in the main app's node_modules folder. This tells the compiler to look in the main app's node_modules folder before trying to find a node_modules folder further up the tree.